# How to run retry fro the pending header items using futures = session.get(url, headers=header for header in headers1)

Tags: python, requests-futures

I am creating my header list using this function from CSV file.

Comment: def createHeader():
    global a, b,headers1
    a=[]
    b=[]
    headers1=[]
    print("Opening the CSV file and reading data")
    with open('Data_File.csv') as file:
        reader =csv.reader(file)
        for item in reader:
            a.append(item[0])
            b.append(item[1].lower())
    while ("" in a):
        a.remove("")
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
          y = {i:j}
          headers1.append(y)
    print(headers1)

Comment: While running it, getting the timeout error sometime and it is getting failed, able to manage with a retry method , but it rerun the entire header list again

Comment: I want to execute only for the remaining header list